# @RequestMapping in spring

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, controller

i'm new in spring mvc and i don't understand how to use the annotation @RequestMapping.
this's the code of the controller login:

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping(value="/")
 public class LoginController {
       protected final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);

       @Autowired // The authenticate service is automatically injected into this controller
       private AuthenticateService service;

       @RequestMapping(value = "{pathLogin}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String initFrom(@PathVariable("pathLogin") String path) {
            log.info("Return on log view...."+path);
            return "login";
        }

       @RequestMapping(value = "{pathOnSubmit}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public String onSubmit(@RequestParam("username") String username, 
                          @RequestParam("password") String password,  @PathVariable("pathOnSubmit") String path, HttpServletRequest request) {
          String message = "Invalid credential or Inexistent Username";
          if(!service.authentification(username, password)) {
               path = "login";
               return "login";
          }else {
             path = "homePage";
             return "homePage";
          }
        }
```

And the form in login.jsp is:

```
    <form method="post" action="">
          //here some input for the form
    </from>
```

when i make a `GET` request in URL:`"http:/...../Project_administration/login.htm"` everything it's okay. But when i submit making a `POST` request, in the controller if i put the correct username and password, `ELSE block` is execute and the request is forwarding in `"/WEB-INF/jsp/homePage.jsp"` in `InternalResourceView`. The problem is The URL, which didn't change in `"http:/...../Project_administration/homePage.htm"`. I don't known why.
Someone can help??
Thank...

Comment: It didn't change because it executed a forward instead of a redirect.

Comment: i resolved it.. i change the `return "login"` on the `method onSubmit()` in `return "redirect:login.html"` and now it's ok.. thx